# How to get last 5 mins record from SQL database table?

Tags: sql-server

How to get last 5 mins records from SQL table.

E.g: I have one table name called Student.

```
ID Name        StartTime
-- ----------  ----------------------
1  abc         2016-05-18 08:00:29.587 
2  xxx         2016-05-18 08:05:30.287
3  xyz         2016-05-18 08:10:30.287
```

Consider now the Time is **8:15am**. I would like to get last **5mins** record from `"Student"` table.

E.g: 
I need **"xyz"** user information.

I tried below queries not working.

```
select * from Student where startTime is not null and startTime <  GetDate() and startTime > dateadd(minute, -5, GetDate())
```

But i am getting null values from student table.

How to do it. please help me to solve.

Comment: Based on your explanation there's no reason you'd get no records. What datatype is StartTime? What happens if you run `select dateadd(minute, -5, GetDate()), getdate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Student where startTime is not null and startTime > DATEADD(minute, -5,  GETUTCDATE())
```

try this code

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to the seconds component of the datetime. What you want to do is make sure you remove the `seconds` from the datetime. Here is how:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 120) + ':00' AS DATETIME)
```

And then use the result in the comparison, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    ID      INT,
    Name    VARCHAR(3),
    StartTime   DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES
(1, 'abc',  '2016-05-18 08:00:29.587 '),
(2, 'xxx',  '2016-05-18 08:05:30.587 '),
(3, 'xyz',  '2016-05-18 08:10:30.587 ');

DECLARE @currDate DATETIME = '2016-05-18 08:15:59.000'

SELECT @currDate =  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @currDate, 120) + ':00' AS DATETIME)

SELECT  *
FROM Student
WHERE startTime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, @currDate)


DROP TABLE Student;
```

---

RESULT:

```
ID          Name StartTime
----------- ---- -----------------------
3           xyz  2016-05-18 08:10:30.587
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM   Student 
WHERE  STARTIME >= Dateadd(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
```